# What's wrong in using sparql package in R to run Movie star graph visualization? Error with the locahost

Tags: r

I'm trying to run [this](http://linkedscience.org/tools/sparql-package-for-r/sparql-package-for-r-gephi-movie-star-graph-visualization-tutorial/) in R software. When I get at this point:

```
res <- SPARQL(endpoint,q,ns=prefix,extra=options)$results
```

The program give me the error:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    Failed to connect
>   to localhost port 3030: Connection refused

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Did you _uncomment_ this `# endpoint <- "http://localhost:3030/movie/sparql"` step?